# Operating Temperature of Cisco routers

Tags: cisco, router

I am managing a small server room containing different pieces of networking equipment e.g. cisco3900, paloalto appliance, pc routers, various switches. The issue is that our server room has been operating without an air-conditioning unit for a long time already. I maybe stating the obvious here but I am afraid that at some point some of the networking equipment will fail because of the heat if they continue to run with only their built-in fans available for cooling. For example, the cisco3900 router's temperature is at 62 deg C at the moment. Specifically for the Cisco router, do I turn it off, or is it still operating at an acceptable temperature level?

ADDITIONAL DETAILS:
I think, the ambient temperature of the room is close to 30 deg C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the temperature inside of the room?

Read the manufacturer's specifications. They provide the [recommended ambient operating temperature ranges for the Cisco 3900](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/2900/hardware/installation/guide/Hardware_Installation_Guide/Overview.html#43396).

It seems like you should consider cooling for your server room. Portable air conditioners are a common solution to this problem.

Why would you turn the equipment off?

Comment: thanks for this... I guess I did not look hard enough...

Comment: I'm just afraid that it will fail if the equipment continues to run without proper cooling... I think the ambient temperature of the room is around 30 deg C.